# Is there a way to use ninja to build and have cmake out put a sln file as well for vs19?

Tags: c, cmake, ninja

I would like to use ninja to build and cmake to output a sln file so we can use the debug features in vs19.

Comment: What for? generate .sln and let VS invoke the compiler itself.

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: because cmake generates the configuration of the project and VS build system will do what is needed

Comment: How to configure  vs to use ninja as the compiler?

Comment: ninja is not a compiler only the build tool. you do not need it in VS

Comment: how do I produce a solution with cmake file so I can debug in VS and use ninja to build and msvc to compile?

Comment: Just open the CMake project in Visual Studio directly. You don't need to create a solution.